# I was sleeping suddenly I woke up after couple of seconds I got ejaculation I didn't got any erection or sexual fantasy. Will my ghusl break by this

Tags: practical-islam, nocturnal-emission

I was sleeping suddenly I woke up and after some seconds I got a ejaculation I wasn't erected nor have a desire it was on it's own. Will my ghusl break?

Answer (score 1):

What you’re referring to is a wet dream. Wet dreams break ur ghusl and as a result you will need to do a ghusl to purify yourself

Comment: Yes, but I woke up before happening

Comment: Same principle applies, after semen emission a ghusl is required

Comment: Please do back up this answer with an [edit] to add a source.

Answer (score 1):

Ejaculation breaks the ghusl, so it must be done again, regardless of the reason for ejaculation.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge, any discharge of semen, regardless of the preconditions, results in needing ghusl.

Comment: While I believe you are correct, please [edit] in a source to back up this claim.